# Android studio and git

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control, projects-and-solutions

I have tried using git with android studio a few times now and always run to the same problem when another developer starts working on the project. its like Android Studio does not recognize it as a project any more.

[image]

this happened today after doing a git pull

i have tried adding the gitignore as is suggested in the first answer on  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649492/trying-to-use-git-with-android-studio)

but this did not help. i have a safe backup of this project but i do need to get git working for me properly.

I have followed a few different posts different suggestions on setting up git with android studio but they all have landed me in this situation. 
Some project file must be getting changed when run on other developers machine.

is there a file(s) that i can copy from my back up to fix this issue or additional files that need to be ignored?

[image]

Comment: your 'settings.gradle' is empty i think. try solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem for me-
add this line to settings.gradle file

```
include ':app'
```

for accessing settings.gradle use 'project' view instead of 'android'.

Then go to file->close project -> open existing android studio project-> select project. if that does not work try file-> invalidate cache and restart

Comment if you dont understand what i mean

Comment: well im happy to help !  ill sleep tonight knowing someone else didnt have to go though 2 days of torture before figuring it out lol. btw I had to do it everytime i pulled the code, so if you figure out a permanent solution then comment here for another one of our fellow comrades who might come wandering some day, looking for answers to his lifes woes :) Im sure it has something to do with git and gitignore

Comment: after this worked android studio did not pick up that the project was under git. Did you have this issue aswell?

Comment: well close and reopen again. android studio will prompt to "add root". you can check in the project folder too , there surely will be a .git file(possible 'hidden' so enable 'view hidden files and folders'). as long as that file is present your project will be under git

Answer (score 1):

Please try after putting below in .gitignore of both app & project module.

In Project module's .gitignore -

```
 .gradle
    /local.properties
    /.idea/workspace.xml
    /.idea/libraries
    .DS_Store
    /build
    /captures
    *.iml
```

& in app module's .gitignore -

```
/build
app.iml
```

[image: Check Screenshot]

Hopefully it will work well for you.

Comment: Sorry dont know much  about modules which directories are each or these in. Does  the first snippet go in .gitignore in root of project and the second in the app dir?

Comment: updated comments. hopefully now you will able to know.

Comment: I have done this but 1.) wont the ignored files still be in the remote and 2.) how do i get the project to run as the only local files i have changed are the 2 gitignore files

Comment: first pull your project again and add these changes in respective files and do same with all of your project's peers. then from next time most probably  it will not create any problem while using git on android studio.