# Github desktop not showing changes from Android Studio

Tags: android, git, github

This has recently just started happening. Whenever I make changes on an Android project the changes don't show up on my Github desktop for me to commit and sync. I instead have to commit and push changes from Android Studio itself. The history of my commits from Android Studio show but not recent changes.

Can someone shed light onto why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the .git folder and the working tree used both by Android Studio (as [shown in those screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30649492/6309)) and [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) are the same.

Try and import in GitHub Desktop the exact path of the repo used by Android Studio.

Comment: @JoséMaría Why CVS though? it should be an IntelliJ IDEa help page about Git instead, no? Like https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/clone-repository-dialog.html?

Comment: @JoséMaría No, my point was: you were linking to an help page about the version control tool CVS instead of Git.